# How to insert duplicate values into a primary key column in a table in postgres?

Tags: postgresql

I had a table as below

```
CREATE TABLE test (
    id character varying(300)  ,
    name     character varying(400) 
    );
ALTER TABLE test ADD PRIMARY KEY (Id);
```

I had the following insert statements

```
insert into test(id,name)values('1','ram')`;
insert into test(id,name)values('1','sam')`;
```

In the above insert statements i am trying to insert duplicate 'id'. I am getting the error saying duplicate value the value already exits.

Is their any other way that we can declare a column as primary key and duplicate the primary key

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish by duplicating the **Primary Key**?

Answer (score 1):

The point of a (primary) key is that it is unique. So, no, you simply cannot insert duplicate values in key columns.

You may face an [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem) though and might probably ask a new question where you describe, **in detail**, what you actually want to do and how *this* can be achieved.